# How to access razor variable inside javascript file?

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I have a razor page that is grabbing a boolean from some c# code, like

```
var changeCondition = @bool.Parse(Settings["changeCondition"] ?? "true");
```

I have to use this variable once in a javscript file during an if statement, ideally something like

```
if (changeCondition) {
     run this
}
```

But I have almost no knowledge of javascript. I looked up a few other questions, and they didn't make much sense to me. Is there any way to get the value of the variable in javascript either from the c# directly or the razor page? Not making any changes to it, just need to know the value. I'd appreciate a very detailed explanation because I don't know very many js concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer that worked for me. In the cshtml file, there was already a section defined as

```
@section scripts{
     ...
     var changeCondition = @bool.Parse(Settings["changeCondition") ?? "true");
}
```

with many variables inside of it. I just added my variable at the end and I was able to reference it directly in the javascript file

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var changeCondition = @bool.Parse(Settings["changeCondition"] ?? "true");
    if (changeCondition) {
      run this;
    }
</script>
```